# Methods for differentiating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I just wanted to know some methods for differentiating an integral. I only know 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt = h(g(x))g'(x) - h(f(x))f'(x)$$. Are there any more? I remember my sir saying that there is a method in which partial derivative is take inside the integral. Please elaborate on this topic.

Comment: if you have the integral of, say, $h(x,t)$, then you can differentiate under the integral sign but only under some conditions.

Comment: Maybe you mean $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^bf(x,t)dt=\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dt$$

Comment: If you are differentiating in terms of a variable that is in the bounds of the integral, then the fact that you stated is the only fact you would ever need. If instead the variable is in the integrand, then you can take the derivative into the integral under certain conditions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule